# Google script automatically close UI after clicking link button

Tags: user-interface, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script that opens a UI which is used to open another spreadsheet

When I click to open the link I would like the UI to close automatically if possible.

```
function ServiceSetServiceSheets(){
var html = "<a href='https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'; target='_blank'>Open The Service Sheet</a>";
  var anchor = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html).setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME).setHeight(60).setWidth(150);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(anchor,"Click the link to")
 
  }
```

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 1):

In your situation, how about using [`google.script.host.close()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/host#close()) as follows? Please modify your script as follows.

#### From:

```
var html = "<a href='https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'; target='_blank'>サービス シートを開く";
```

#### To:

```
var html = "<a href='https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'; target='_blank' onclick='google.script.host.close()'>サービス シートを開く";
```

- By this modification, when you click the link, the dialog is closed by `google.script.host.close()`.

Comment: About `Many thanks #Tanaike that works perfectly. Regards Ben`, welcome. Thank you for letting me know. I'm glad your issue was resolved. If your question was solved, please push an accept button. Other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question that can be solved. And I think that your issue and solution will be useful for them. If you don't find the button, feel free to tell me. https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 1):

Example:

Execute launchClickAndClose();

```
function launchClickAndClose() {
  let html = '<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><base target="_top"></head><body>';
  html += '<input type="button" value="Doit" onClick="doSomething();" />';
  html += '<script>function doSomething(){google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(() => {google.script.host.close()}).doitontheserver();}</script>'
  html += '</body></html>';
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html), "Close Automatically")

}

function doitontheserver() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ss.toast("Doing it");
  return;
}
```